# Android Application To Store Image And Text And Show Via ListView

Tags: android, image, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I am making an Android application that needs to show an image with text next to it in a ListView. I was wondering what would be the best way, to use an SQLite database or phone storage? I would preferably like to use SQLite though. I would also appreciate any examples that anyone may have, I have looked around and as my request is pretty specific I've not found anything very relavent.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where these images are being loaded from, are they chosen from the gallery by the user? If so, what worked for me was to just store the path to the images in SQLite and then use AsyncDrawables as laid out in this article:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

To dynamically load them without worry of running out of memory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and yes chosen from the gallery by the user, I wasn't totally sure how I'd get it to work. I will take a look at the link now, thanks again.

Comment: I'm pretty much a beginner and reading that confused me and I'm mostly confused about how I'll create an SQLite database that links to the ListView. Thank you for the help though, still much appreciated